# Creating char Trie in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, variant

I'm trying to build an initial Trie structure in OCaml where the edges are the char. So the string "ESK" would be mapped as:

`[('E', [('S', [('K', [])])])]`

My definition for this is:

```
type trie = Trie of (char * trie) list
```

However, on implementing an `add` function with:

```
 let rec add_string str =
    let key = String.get str 0 in
    if String.length str = 1 then
      (key, empty_trie) :: []
    else
      (key, add_string (tail str)) :: []
```

for `add (tail str)` the compiler gives me:

```
Error: This expression has type (char * trie) list
       but an expression was expected of type trie
```

I'm a bit puzzled by this as I have not defined a `trie` as `(char * trie) list`?

`tail` is simply `let tail str = String.slice str 1 (String.length str)` and `empty_trie` is `let empty_trie = Trie([])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a more idiomatic way of writing the function would be

```
let rec add_string str =
  let key = str.[0] in
  if String.length str = 1 then
    Trie [key, empty_trie]
  else
    Trie [key, add_string (tail str)]
```

Then there are two problems left with `add_string`: first it reallocates a new string at each iteration. It is simpler and more efficient to keep track of the current position:

```
let add_string str =
  let rec add_string_aux pos str =
    if pos = String.length str then empty_trie
    else
      let key = str.[pos] in
      Trie [key, add_string_aux (pos+1) str] in
  add_string_aux 0 str
```

The second problem is that the function is ill-named since it does not add a string to an existing trie but build a trie from a string: `from_string` or `of_string` might be better names.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. `Trie` should be explicitly used:

```
let rec add_string str =
  let key = String.get str 0 in
  if String.length str = 1 then
    (key, empty_trie) :: []
  else
    (key, Trie (add_string (tail str))) :: []
```

This will result in `add_string "ESK"` producing:

`(char * trie) list = [('E', Trie [('S', Trie [('K', Trie [])])])]`

Comment: Or, if you want `add_string` to return a `trie`: `Trie [(key, empty_trie)]` and `Trie [(key, add_string (tail str))]`, respectively.

Comment: That's a much better idea. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll mark as answered.